# java passing a variable when class name is used twice in same class

Tags: java, function, class

```
public class test extends AbstractTableModel {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }

    public String valuePass(int rowIn)
    {
        String value = "open";
        return value;
    }


    test(mdpTEST parentPanel) {
        m_parentPanel = parentPanel;
    }

    ...
}

import demo.test;
public class order{

    public void new() 
    {
        test blah = new test(null);
        String text = blah.valuePass(0);    
    }

}
```

In the code above, "blah" should be referencing the class "test" which is public, however I'm told to change the visibility of "test()" to public as I get an error in the line: "test blah = new test(null);". I'm confused at why "public class test" is not being referenced by "blah" and how the second instance of "test()" is being utilized here. I appreciate any help in understanding this problem!

Comment: Please show real code, as close to a valid [mcve] as you can get and not blah-code, as well as the complete error message.

Comment: If demo.test has multiple constructors, it's possible that passing 'null' in isn't hitting the public constructor you expect. If you want to use the default constructor, it should just be `test blah = new test();`

Comment: Your constructor is package private and you seem to reference your constructor from another package (otherwise you would not have to import `demo.test`). So make the constructor public and everything should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues with the code that you have shown

1) You cannot have `new()` as method name as `new` it is a keyword

2) Line `test blah = new test(null);` is calling a constructor of a test class which is in a different package. So default visibility is applied to test(...) constructor in test class. And as per java visibility rule, you have to make it public to access it in a different package

Do these changes and your code should work fine

Comment: This makes sense, in the same package I also call the constructor but I didn't need to make it public I didn't realize the issues of visibility in different packages. Thank you!